# Sorting elements in a row in a 2 dimensional array using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a row of 2 dimensional array. But I am unable to achieve it.

For eg:

```
    7 6 5
    5 7 6
    8 2 9
    2 3 4
```

to be like this:

```
    5 6 7
    5 6 7
    2 8 9
    2 3 4
```

Below is my code:

```
void sort(int *a,int num){
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<num-1;i++){
        for (j=0;j<num-i-1;j++){
            if (*((a+i*3)+j)>*((a+i*3)+j+1)){
                temp=*((a+i*3)+j);
                *((a+i*3)+j)=*((a+i*3)+j+1);
                *((a+i*3)+j+1)=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            printf("%d ",*((a+i*3)+j));
        printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Output of the above code:

```
    6 5 5 
    7 6 7 
    2 8 9 
    2 3 4
```

Can anyone tell what's the problem in the code? 
Thanks in advance. :D

EDIT:
So should the above code look like this?

```
    void sort(int *a,int num){
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<num-1;i++){
        for (j=0;j<num-i-1;j++){
            if (*(*(a+i)+j)>*(*(a+i)+j+1)){
               temp=*(*(a+i)+j);
               *(*(a+i)+j)=*(*(a+i)+j+1);
               *(*(a+m)+j+1)=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no 2D array. Just a pointer to `int`. Using a 2D array (resp. pointer to a 1D array) and the index-operatorwould make this mess halfway readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is too complicated, so you did many small mistakes in it.

You should separate sorting of each row somehow, like this:

```
for (row = 0; row < num; row++) {
    sort_row(a + row * 3);
}
```

The function `sort_row` sorts just one row, so it's going to be easier to write and test (BTW I replaced the nondescript name `i` by `row`).

The function `sort_row` should do normal bubble sort. You can even use the standard library `qsort` instead (for purposes of testing).

Note that standard bubble-sort algorithm is implemented with two nested loops. If you want to implement your code without a separate `sort_row` function call, you will need *three* nested loops.

Comment: Thx, anatolyg I will keep in mind to use library function next time... :D

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems:

1) the loops are not running for n times, Hence the condition in for loop should be changed to `i < num` instead of `i < num - 1` which skips the last row

2) From your code it seems you want to use bubble sort technique. The sort is O(n^2) and that's why require the swapping if statement to run (n - 1)times for each element, hence you should include one more for loop inside the j-for loop.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much...didn't think for the another loop. Thx once again. :D